# How do I expand the fourth-order Runge-Kutta method to the seventh-order?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, runge-kutta-methods

I'm being asked this question and I don't quite understand how to do it.

I kinda know how the fourth-order Runge-Kutta method works.

$K_1 = hf(x_n,y_n)$

$K_2 = hf(x_n+\frac{h}{2},y_n+\frac{k_1}{2})$

$K_3 = hf(x_n+\frac{h}{2},y_n+\frac{k_2}{2})$

$K_4 = hf(x_n+\frac{h}{2},y_n+k_3)$

$y_{n+1} = y_n + \frac{k_1}{6}+ \frac{k_2}{3}+ \frac{k_3}{3}+ \frac{k_4}{6}$

But how do I expand this to seventh-order? Is there an equation for $K_n$ I can follow and an equation for $y_{n+1}$ which extends up to $k_7$?

I've seen some higher order Runge-Kutta examples online which uses a Butcher tableau but it all seems really complex to me.

Comment: Classical RK4 is an exception. Only up to second order are the method steps straight-forward, in third order none are this structurally simple. All other 4th order methods have unintuitive coefficient patterns, even if the step times still follow some quadrature rule. From 5th order on everything is ruled by the order conditions that form an algebraic system, it is a small miracle that many of them still have rational coefficients. So yes, to implement them you have to carefully transcribe Butcher tableaux in quite mechanical manner. Or dive deep into the structure of the order conditions.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I see, I guess the answer to this problem would be quite messy. I did, however, find this paper (https://www.researchgate.net/publication/335404423_Solving_initial_value_problem_using_Runge-Kutta_6th_order_method) which shows the Runge-Kutta method in 7 stages. I'm just not sure why the paper is called sixth order when it reaches $K_7$

Comment: It is a coincidence that the number of stages (how much you have to calculate) is equal to the order (how accurate the result is) up to the fourth order. IIRC for fifth order you need six stages, i.e. one "extra" stage, and eventually you need even more "extra" stages to increase the order.

Comment: @DavidK Ah, I see. The question my professor gave me was "Expand the fourth-order Runge-Kutta Method to seventh-order. Here, show the equation for k5, k6, and k7 and the final equation for this method." I'm guessing that the question is just wrong.

I guess

Comment: As example, the Verner67 method uses 8 stages for the (embedded) 6th order method and 10 stages for the order 7 method. One can use both on their own in a fixed-step method.

Comment: Please report back if you learn something new about this task. It could be that your lecturer set you purposefully on a wrong path, so you can discover for yourself that something different happens if the order is larger than 4.

Comment: The cited article is wrong-wrong-wrong. First, the coefficients in the $k_6$ line do not add up to $\frac16$, which would be necessary for basic consistency. Checking the order conditions gives also an error already in the second order terms. And in the article itself, the stability polynomial of an explicit order 6 method should be in the start be exactly the partial sum of the exponential up to the degree equal to the order. Here that would be the 6th degree, but in the computed polynomial only the trivial constant and linear terms are exact. So please do not cite.

Comment: In later publications this has been corrected, the $\frac{11}{20}$ has to be $\frac{11}{24}$. Then consistency and order are correct, but in comparison with the reference method of that paper of order 5, the new method with 1/2 the step size still has an 100 times larger error.